# Inner join in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a working query, but would like to know if there is a more elegant way to do it. I have a Product table and a Manufacturer table.

The relationships are as follows:

```
Manufacturer > hasMany > Product
Product > belongsTo > Manufacturer
```

My query is:

```
$products = \App\Product::join('manufacturers', 
        'products.manufacturer_id', '=', 'manufacturers.id')
    ->where('manufacturers.name', 'like', $needle)
    ->orWhere('products.name', 'like', $needle);
```

Is this right? Is there a better way? Maybe without using `join` in a Eloquent model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create relationship in your `Product` model:

```
public function manufacturer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Manufacturer::class, 'foreign_key');
}
```

and then you can use

```
$products = \App\Product::whereHas('manufacturer', function ($query) use ($needle) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', $needle);
})->orWhere('name', 'like', $needle);
```

Comment: You forgot closure for needle.